# Find angle BCC¹ on triangular prism

Tags: geometry, vectors, solid-geometry

In a triangular prism $ABCA¹B¹C¹$,  $|AB|=c$, $|BC|=a$, $|CA|=b$, $\angle BAA¹=\alpha$, $\angle CAA¹=\beta$. Find $\angle BCC¹$

Vector methods are preferred.

Comment: Please show your effort before entering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
$BC=AC-AB$, $CC^1=AA^1=BB^1$,
$\cos\angle BCC^1=\frac{BC.CC^1}{|BC|\cdot|CC^1|}
=\frac{(AC-AB).CC^1}{|BC|\cdot|CC^1|}
=\frac{AC.CC^1-AB.CC^1}{|BC|\cdot|CC^1|}
=\frac{AC.AA^1-AB.AA^1}{|BC|\cdot|CC^1|}
=\frac{|AC|\cdot|AA^1|\cdot\cos\angle CAA^1
-|AB|\cdot|AA^1|\cdot\cos\angle BAA^1}{|BC|\cdot|CC^1|}
=\frac{|AC|\cdot\cos\angle CAA^1
-|AB|\cdot\cos\angle BAA^1}{|BC|}
=\frac{b\cos\beta-c\cos\alpha}{a}$